# CakePHP cache control for asset files (images, CSS, etc)

Tags: cakephp, caching

What's the best way to use CakePHP to control the Expires headers for image and CSS files?

My host unfortunately doesn't support `mod_expires` or `mod_headers`, so I can't simply set these values in an `.htaccess` file. Right now there's no cache control for my files and a lot of unnecessary requests are made.

What's the most elegant way to pipe requests for asset files through Cake and set the appropriate headers via `header()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best, not even necessarily Cake-specific way, is to create a script in `/webroot` that adds the headers, then use `.htaccess` directives to pipe requests for `./css/*` and `./img/*` through that file. I was just hoping there might be some functionality like this built into Cake already. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a helper which takes the filename and then returns a URL to a PHP script which fetches the file and adds the necessary header. You can see an example of a basic helper here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/image-resize-helper

Comment: The extra step with the Helper seems pretty unnecessary, thanks for the response anyway. :)

Comment: The reason for the helper is so that you don't have to manually rewrite all your URLs when outputting your assets. If you don't mind doing this, then you can certainly just write a PHP script that writes the headers and then include that script when referencing an asset using CakePHP.