# Cache and compress only some CSS files with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, iis-6

I would like to speed up my web application as much as possible and I was thinking about the possibility of caching CSS files as well as some JS files and maybe, add some compression to some of them.

I want to cache only some files, as other might suffer from constant modifications and the user would need always the latest version to navigate through the site.

I have been taking a look at this post:
[How to cache static content (css, images,js files) in CakePHP2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681869/how-to-cache-static-content-css-images-js-files-in-cakephp)

As well as to this one:
[CakePHP cache control for asset files (images, CSS, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181074/cakephp-cache-control-for-asset-files-images-css-etc?rq=1)

But it caches ALL files. 
Is there any way to cache only some files or to avoid caching a list of them?

Im using CakePHP2.0 over Windows 2003 Server and IIS 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a CakePHP Combinator Plugin that does exactly what you want: https://github.com/joshuapaling/CakePHP-Combinator-Plugin

You can combine all your files - even the ones that change fairly often, because the helper will automatically detect when files have changed, and will create a new cached version. But, if for whatever reason you only want to cache some files, that's easy too. It can also compress CSS and JS.

Another option is Mark Story's asset compress plugin: https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress

Mark's plugin has more features, like built in LESS and CoffeeScript support - but it's more involved. Mine is simpler and easier.

Comment: What if I want to combine multiple JS files but some of them are already minified? Could I still doing it without generating errors?

Comment: Also, when the cached files are deleted?

Comment: Hi Steve, if some javascript files are already minified, that shouldn't be a problem. And cache files are never deleted. You'll need to manually delete them every so often if leaving them around bothers you.

Comment: Also, for the record, as of the last couple of months, I've started using SASS / Compass for CSS, and I'm using CodeKit (http://incident57.com/codekit/) so now all my javascript and CSS preprocessing, combining and compression happens client side, as I develop, every time I save a file. It's an awesome workflow - you should consider it. And it has removed the need for server-side compression, so I'm no longer developing / using the Combinator Plugin. However, if you still wish to use it, it's not broken or anything, and should continue to work for all Cake 2.x versions.

Comment: That's not free, is it? And, why is it better to do it at the client? And... is only for Mac, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, not free. $25. And yep, only for mac. The main thing I like about it is that it makes it easy to use Sass / Compass as a CSS preprocessor, which is a lot more efficient than writing plain CSS. And sorry, 'client side' is the wrong term (and I can't edit my damn comment!). The compression happens on my machine, as I develop. So each time I save a file, it gets compressed, combined with other relevant files, and saved. I just think that's a tidier workflow, having that happen at development-time on my computer, as opposed to at run-time on the server. But either way works.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a timestamp or random string to the ones you dont want cached.

```
/css/something.css?random_string
```